# Projecting a parametric curve to a plane

Tags: integration, parametric

I have a parametric equation: x = t^3 and y = t + 2t. I would like to do a line integral of this curve up to the plane z = 5.

Basically, I would like to find the area of the "walls" formed when projecting this curve up to the plane z = 5. Let's say we are considering the bounds from t = 0 to t = 1.

Would it simply be the line integral of the parametric curve over the bounds multiplied by 5?

Comment: How is it being projected? For example does one consider rays from some point below the xy plane through points of the curve, and find where these rays cross $z=5$?

Comment: Is your curve in the $xy$-plane?

Comment: The parametric curve lives in the xy plane. We are simply "stretching" the curve up to meet the plane z = 5 and finding the area of the walls.

Comment: Then you've essentially just got a rectangle that you've bent around in some way.  So arc length times 5 is the area.

Comment: This "wall" is 5 units high for the entire length of the path?  The the area of the wall is 5 x length of the path.  $\int ||dx/dt,dy/dt|| dt$

Comment: Is $y=t+2t$ or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curve lies in the $xy$-plane, and so the walls you mention form a right-cylinder.

The area will be the height times the length of the base.

For a parametric curve, the length of the base is given by

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d t}\right)^2}~\mathrm d t$$

Here $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the start and end values of $t$.